# Locating my static assets when publishing on Azure with Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WebAssembly (Core Hosted) solution for testing purpose. I test 2 different scenario:

- 1st one: publishing the server side on Azure and the client side inside a storage account.
- 2nd one: publishing everything on Azure

**FYI my solution is composed of 3 projects**

- Client
- Server
- Shared (Razor Class Library) <-- with some Blazor components + css + js + ...

**The 1st scenario**

For publishing the server side: right click on the Server project then choose Publish, then choose Azure (fill in settings,...) then start the publishing process.

For publishing the client side: right click on the Client project then choose Publish, then choose Folder, then start the publishing process. Next, I used the *Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer* app to upload files (located in \bin\Release\net5.0\browser-wasm\publish\wwwroot\ ) inside the storage account.

I clearly see that:

- my static assets (css, js, ...) are inside \wwwroot\ _content\
- my dll files (Prolog.Client.dll, Prolog.Shared.dll among many others) are inside \wwwroot\ _framework

And everything is working as expected.

**The 2nd scenario**

For publishing everything on Azure, simply right click on the Server project then choose Publish, then choose Azure (fill in settings,...) then start the publishing process.

Everything is working as expected.

Thanks to the kudu website (https:// myappxxx. **scm** .azurewebsites.net/) I can browse files on my server. I easily located my dll files inside the wwwroot folder on the server (Prolog.Client.dll, Prolog.Server.dll, Prolog.Shared.dll among many others).

**But what is obscure to me is to know where are physically located my static assets ? Where are my css and js files ?**

Can I use the Kudu website to browse through folders to find them ?

[image]

For example, below, my javascript file named *main.js*. I tried to use the Kudu website to locate it on my server where it has been published without luck. I don't find any *_content* folder nor *Prolog.Shared* folder.

[image]

---

**UPDATE**

Thanks to Mister Magoo : I tried the "App Service Editor (Preview)" under the "Development Tools" section of the Azure Portal for my App Service. From there I was able to browse through all my files, including my static assets. It was pretty similar to the Kudu console... except that in my Kudu console some files and folders were missing. I noticed a warning message in my Kudu console:

[image]

So I added this key in my Local Storage and bingo! All my missing files were suddenly visible. Problem solved.

Comment: Have you tried the "App Service Editor (Preview)" under the "Development Tools" section of the Azure Portal for your App Service? I can see the `_content` files there for mine.

Comment: @MisterMagoo thanks to you I was able to solve my problem. Please post your comment inside an answer in order to benefit the bounty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried the "App Service Editor (Preview)" under the "Development Tools" section of the Azure Portal for your App Service? I can see the _content files there for mine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks again @Mister Magoo you'll benefit of the bounty in 10 hours (requirement of SO).